# Perform the following operation: $\frac{d}{dx} (\sqrt[5]{x} + \frac{2}{x^3} )$

Tags: calculus

Need help solving $\frac{d}{dx} \left (\sqrt[5]{x} + \frac{2}{x^3} \right )$

So far I changed it to $x^{1/5} + 2x^{-1/3}$, and then changed that to $1/5x^{-6/5} - 6x^{-4}$ but I don't think that is right.

Comment: Is it $\frac{d}{dx}\left(5\sqrt{x}+\frac{2}{x^3}\right)$ or $\frac{d}{dx}\left(5\sqrt{x}\right)+\frac{2}{x^3}$, something else entirely?

Comment: Or $\frac d{dx}\left(\sqrt[5] x + \frac 2{x^3}\right)$?

Comment: The correct one is the one that "amWhy" has posted. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Very ambiguous usage of latex. Please edit accordingly.

Comment: I think the question should be correct now, someone edited into something that was not what was intended. Check if it looks correct.

Comment: I just saw you guys editing each other thrice.

Comment: It's correct now

Comment: @AvZ: We both edited to correct the post: me the body, Eff the title, and I just edited the title to remove \left(\right).

Comment: @amWhy Yeah, I know. I saw :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sort of close, but I don't understand your changing the second term to $2x^{-1/3}$. It should be $2x^{-3}$. The correct answer is $$\frac 15 x^{-4/5} -6x^{-4} = \frac{1}{5x^{4/5}} - \frac 6{x^4}$$

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't subtract the 1 from 1/5 correctly.

Comment: Correct. You had the right idea, though.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: $(c\cdot f(x))' = c\cdot f'(x), f(x) = \sqrt{x} = x^{\frac{1}{2}}, (x^{\alpha})' = \alpha\cdot x^{\alpha-1}$